# How to initialize model from segue method

Tags: uiviewcontroller, model, uitableview, uipageviewcontroller, uistoryboardsegue

Hi I have a UITableViewController which is populated by Playlist objects, which they hold Song objects. What I want is when the user taps a playlist name in my TVC, to fire a UIPageViewController, whose model will me initialized by the playlist that was tapped in the UITableViewController. Then it would show the things I would like in another ViewController.

The UIPageViewController implementation works like this in my app:

ModelController --> RootViewController --> DataViewController (just like Apple's example)

I have everything up and running so far, however I can't initialize properly the model with the playlist that was tapped. In my PlaylistsTVC I have a prepareForSegue method which defines the destination view controller and arr holds the songs of the playlist that was tapped, but I don't know how can I pass it to ModelController.

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
     if (sender)
     {
         if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"Segue"])
        {
            NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
            NSArray *arr = @[[[self.pdc.playlistMasterList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] songs]];
            NSLog(@"arr: %@", arr);
            RootViewController *rvc = (RootViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
            rvc.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES;
        }
    }
```

}

I tried to set an array in my PlaylistDataController class and then create a new instance in the ModelController class, but it didn't work. I also tried to encode and decode the array full of songs in NSUserDefaults and then pass it to the ModelController, just to see if it would work but no luck either.

Can anyone help with how is possible to initialize the model of the page view controller, from the segue method I described above? Or any other idea for that matter would be very welcomed.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

(I'm a bit confused by your controller naming...)

If you want to work with the array in `RootViewController`, then your approach was basically correct. You need a property in rvc and set it in `prepareForSegue`. E.g.:

```
...
RootViewController *rvc = (RootViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
[rvc.theArray initWithArray:arr];
...
```

Comment: Hi SAE. That's the thing, that the model array is not in RootViewController. Is in Model Controller (again, I am following Apple's classes for my page view controller implementation). At the moment I created a global variable from my app delegate and it's working, but I m not thrilled with it.

Comment: As I said: make a NSArray property in the `RootViewController` class and set it like in my code example. This is the normal approach of passing data between view controllers.